BlocConsumer closes but BlocProvider should be higher priority?
When I open up the profile page, the it builds the ProfileBloc, which then the body would init the GetProfile event, everything works fine but when I move to another page then get back to the profile page, the body is closed and it gives out an error 'cannot add new event after close'. Here's my code of the parts that could be wrong
in profile_body
class ProfilePageBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePageBody({super.key, required this.userProfileModel});

  final UserProfileModel userProfileModel;

  @override
  State<ProfilePageBody> createState() => _ProfilePageBodyState();
}

class _ProfilePageBodyState extends State<ProfilePageBody> {
  List<String> yourFollowingsUid = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context
        .read<ProfileBloc>()
        .add(GetUserProfile(widget.userProfileModel.uid));
    /* context
        .read<ProfileBloc>()
        .add(GetUserFollowings(Supabase.instance.client.auth.currentUser!.id)); */
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<ProfileBloc, ProfileState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) {
        return current is ProfileLoading || current is ProfileLoadingSuccess;
      },
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is ProfileLoadingFailed) {
          buildToast(toastType: ToastType.error, msg: state.message);
        }
        if (state is ProfileLoadingSuccess) {}
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ProfileLoading) {
          return const ProfileShimmer();
        } else if (widget.userProfileModel != null) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppSize.s10),
            child: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () async {
                context.read<ProfileBloc>().add(GetUserProfile(
                      widget.userProfileModel.uid,
                    ));
              },
              child: ListView(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          profileWidget(
                              imageUrl: widget.userProfileModel.imageUrl),
                          const SizedBox(height: AppSize.s5),
                          Text(
                            widget.userProfileModel.username,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: AppSize.s5),
                  BioWidget(
                    bio: widget.userProfileModel.bio,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: AppSize.s10),
                  ProfileOptions(
                    user: widget.userProfileModel,
                    user_followings: yourFollowingsUid,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          shape: const Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(width: AppSize.s1),
                          ),
                          child: const Icon(Icons.apps_outlined),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Expanded(
                        child: MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: null,
                          child: Icon(Icons.lock),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const SizedBox();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}


in profile_page
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserProfileModel userProfileModel;

  const ProfilePage({super.key, required this.userProfileModel});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<ProfileBloc, ProfileState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        print('ProfilePage received state: $state');
        if (state is ProfileSignOutSuccess) {
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            AppRoutes.loginRegisterPage,
            (route) => false,
          );
        }
        if (state is ProfileSignOutFailed) {
          print('ProfileSignOutFailed: ${state.message}');
          buildToast(
            toastType: ToastType.error,
            msg: state.message,
          );
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: ProfilePageAppBar(userProfileModel: userProfileModel),
        body: ProfilePageBody(userProfileModel: userProfileModel),
      ),
    );
  }
}


in main
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  await initDependecies();
  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => serviceLocator<AuthBloc>()),
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => serviceLocator<CameraBloc>()),
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => serviceLocator<ProfileBloc>()),
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => serviceLocator<HashtagBloc>()),
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => serviceLocator<SplashBloc>()),
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => serviceLocator<HomeBloc>()),
    ],
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
}

app_routes
class AppRoutes {
  static const String loginRegisterPage = '/login_register_page';
  static const String forgotPasswordPage = '/forgot_password_page';
  static const String profilePage = '/profile_page';
  static const String viewPostPage = '/view_post_page';
  static const String screenWrapper = '/screen_wrapper';
  static const String splashPage = "/splash_page";
  static const String searchPage = "/search_page";
  static const String editProfilePage = "/edit_profile_page";
}

class AppRouter {
  AppRouter._();
  static final _authBloc = serviceLocator<AuthBloc>();
  //static final _postBloc = sl<PostBloc>();
  static final _profileBloc = serviceLocator<ProfileBloc>();
  static final _searchBloc = serviceLocator<SearchBloc>();

  static Route getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case AppRoutes.splashPage: // If the route is for the splash page
        return PageRouteBuilder(
          transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => _authBloc,
            child: const SplashPage(),
          ),
        );

      case AppRoutes.profilePage:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BlocProvider<ProfileBloc>(
            create: (context) => _profileBloc,
            child: ProfilePage(
              userProfileModel: settings.arguments as UserProfileModel,
            ),
          ),
        );

      case AppRoutes.editProfilePage:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BlocProvider<ProfileBloc>(
            create: (context) => _profileBloc,
            child: const EditProfilePage(),
          ),
        );

      case AppRoutes.loginRegisterPage:
        return PageRouteBuilder(
          transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => _authBloc,
            child: const LogInOrRegisterPage(),
          ),
        );

      case AppRoutes.screenWrapper: // If the route is for the splash page
        return PageRouteBuilder(
          transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => _authBloc,
            child: ScreenWrapper(
              user: settings.arguments as UserProfileModel,
            ),
          ),
        );

      case AppRoutes.forgotPasswordPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
            create: (context) => _authBloc,
            child: const ForgotPasswordPage(),
          ),
        );

      case AppRoutes.searchPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BlocProvider<SearchBloc>(
            create: (context) => _searchBloc,
            child: SearchPage(
              userInfo: settings.arguments as UserProfileModel,
            ),
          ),
        );

      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const NoRouteFound(),
        );
    }
  }
}

class NoRouteFound extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoRouteFound({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text(AppStrings.noRoute)),
    );
  }
}


You haven't provided enought code. Where are you closing the BLoC?

I don't think I added a dispose anywhere in the code.

You once created BlocProvider in the main class,
and must not again create it.
otherwise, if you want to create again or create for the first time you must create it at ProfilePage not in AppRouter.
